# How to merge in python based on condition?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, merge

I would like to know if there is a possible way to merge two dataframes by giving an 'if' statement.
For example

**df**

```
number account_name  classification
     1        name         named
     2        place        partner
     3        animal       class
     4        thing        territory
     5        dog          home
```

**df1**

```
account_name   Number   country
name            1         xx
place           2         xy
animal          7         yz
dog             8         zx
```

I am looking for a code like below

```
pd.merge(df,df1, on= 'account_name') if df[number] == df1[number]
```

the result sould be like

```
number  account_name  classification  number Country
     1        name         named          1      xx
     2        place        partner        2      xy
```

I tried the lambda function as well, code was

```
x['nn'] = x.apply(lambda y: pd.merge(df, df1, on = 'account_name')  if df[number] == df1[number] else 1, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need add column to parameter `on`:

```
df = pd.merge(df,df1, on= ['account_name', 'number']) 
print (df)
   number account_name classification country
0       1         name          named      xx
1       2        place        partner      xy
```

But if column names are different use parameters `left_on` and `right_on` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
df = pd.merge(df, 
              df1, 
              left_on= ['account_name', 'number'], 
              right_on= ['account_name', 'Number']) 
print (df)
   number account_name classification  Number country
0       1         name          named       1      xx
1       2        place        partner       2      xy
```

Comment: Was it always this simple. I've spent crazy numbers of hours thinking and trying to merge. Once I merged for all possible matches of 40k records and then merged again on second column. Thanks.. Solved big problem of my life